# Paypal Sandbox: Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time

Tags: laravel, paypal

requires:
 
 1. Laravel 5.5 
 2. paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*

also:
My paypal account is Egyption , and not attached to any credit card

Problem: 
The sandbox buyer account fail to accomplish the payment and says:

Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time

Comment: Check in the paypal log file or the `laravel.log` inside `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Thanks for attention,  I fix it.  the code was correct the problem was that the seller account was Egyptian, somehow it wan not accepted by PayPal.